# Find numbers which are a product of two 3 digit numbers (Project Euler #4)

Tags: c++, algorithm

The original question goes like this , we have to find the smallest palindrome less than a given number(given by the user ) which has to be a multiple of two three digit numbers . I got the palindrome part sorted out but am stuck on the "multiple" part . I was able to sort out the prime numbers but cant figure out
 anything else.
EDIT:- Seems I wasn't clear in  my question so here's an example 101101 is a palindrome and also a product of two three digit numbers (of 143 and 107 )which also happens to be the smallest palindrome of this type
Here goes my source code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main(){int t ;
cin >> t ;
for (int a0=0 ; a0<t ; a0++){int n ;
cin >> n ;
while(n>101101){



int num , rev = 0 , dig ;
num = n ;
while(num != 0 ){
    dig = num%10;
    rev= (rev*10) + dig ;
    num = num /10;
}
if (rev==n ){
    cout << n ;
    break ;

}
else {
    n= n -1;
}}}}
```

Comment: Please indent the code to make it readable

Comment: Just loop for the palindrome..a=100..999 and b-100...999

Comment: These kind of questions are hard to solve when you don't give appropriate constraints...Expecting a full quetstion

Comment: It doen't say "prime numbers" anywhere, just "three digit numbers". So you can try 100*100, 100*101, etc until the product is too large (or matches). Then 101*101, 101*102,  etc. if there was no match. (It might be possible to reduce the numbers tested from some patterns, like if it ends in a 1 it cannot be the product of two even numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the code which has a function which will check that whether the palindrome number is a product of two three digit numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool checkMultiple(int num)
{
    for(int i=100 ; i<=999; i++)
{
    for(int j=100 ; j<=999; j++)
    {

        if((i*j) == num) 
        {
           // cout<<i<<"*"<<j<<"="<<num<<endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
     return false;
}

int main()
{
   int t ;
   cin >> t ;
   for (int a0=0 ; a0<t ; a0++)
   {
    int n ;
    cin >> n ;
    while(n>101101)
    {
        int num , rev = 0 , dig ;
        num = n ;
        while(num != 0 )
        {
            dig = num%10;
            rev= (rev*10) + dig ;
            num = num /10;
        }
        if (rev==n )
        {
                bool palindrome = checkMultiple(n);
                if(palindrome) 
                {
                    cout << n ;
                    break ;
                }


        }
        else 
        {
            n= n -1;
        }
    }
 }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No I didn't mean that. I said that the palindrome has to be a product of two three digit numbers  . Eg - 101101 is of 143 and 107 which also happens to be the smallest palindrome of this type

Answer (score 0):

Since you have figured out the palindrome part, try this for the multiple part:

```
  1.check if it is a multiple of a 3 digit num (% operator)
  2.if you get one (call n1) ,run the loop again for another similar 3         digit num other than n1, then you've got your palindrome.
  3.then run another outtermost loop which executes till you get your result, checking each possible palin as mentioned above.
```